# React - State Error when loading image

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, svg, webpack

I'm getting a strange issue in React, when trying to display an image. The code causing this is an `<img src={'./assets/logo.svg'} />` tag. However, despite the error message, the image displays.

The error message is the following: [image]

This is the component code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
require('../img/logo.svg');

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);        
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="app-wrapper">
            <img src={'./assets/logo.svg'} />
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pegasus</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need this line? `require('../img/logo.svg');`

Comment: thanks ... don't need it in this example. It was just left over from a different approach to load the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few things, as Martin suggested in the comments, do you need the require statement on line 3?

Firstly, you are also missing a closing parenthesis on your `class`. Secondly, you need to either `import` or `require` the image.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './assets/logo.svg';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app-wrapper">
        <img src={logo} />
        {/* OR <img src={require('./assets/logo.svg')} /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A final note, when you're passing down `props` that are of the type String,
 you do not need to wrap them in `{}`, you can pass them down like such:

```
<Navigation title="My Navigation" />
```